# Un-installation issue of .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: windows-7, installation, .net-framework

When I try to uninstall the .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile, it is not being processed until I uninstall the extended framework. Why does the extended framework need to be uninstalled first?

Comment: This is well documented on Microsoft's website.  The fact it is seems to indicate less then the ideal amount of research was done before asking this question.

Answer (score 3):

MSDN explicits documents that when [Uninstalling the .NET Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee942965%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#uninstalling_net_framework) the extended framework must be uninstalled first. This is because the extended framework is dependent on the .NET 4.0 Client profile and removing just the client would leave it in a broken state.

Answer (score 1):

Likely there is a dependency where the extended framework depends on the base .NET Framework.